# MIPS Assembly: how to know if user inputted values are correctly stored into an array

Tags: arrays, mips

```
.data
      array: .word 0:5
      prompt1: .asciiz "enter number: "
      newline: .asciiz "\n"
.text

      add $t2,$zero,$zero       # initializes counter to 0
      la $s0, array     # stores the beginning of array into $s0

secretcode:

      li $v0, 4                 # prints "enter number: "   
      la $a0, prompt1
      syscall

      li $v0, 5                 # reads in user input
      syscall
      sw $v0, ($s0)     # saves user input into address at $s0
      addi $s0, $s0, 4          # increments address at $s0 by 4 bytes

      addi $t2, $t2, 1          # increments counter by 1
      bne $t2, 5, secretcode    # stops loop when loop executes 5 times 

printsecretcode:

      lw $a0, ($s0)         # print first element
      li $v0, 1
      syscall

      li $v0, 10                # system code halt
      syscall
```

The program is supposed to store 5 user inputted numbers into an array. I tried to print the first value but it comes up as a large number which I assume is an address. How would I print the actual value of the number so that I know it saved correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time you reach your printing code `$s0` contains the address `array + 4*5`, so what you end up printing is the 32-bit number formed by the first four characters of the `"enter number: "` string.

To fix this, add an `la $s0, array` before you try to print the first element.